# Easy Differentiating Twice question?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So, this is the question:

[image: Differentiating twice]

But, how can it be $\cos^2x?$ Doesn't it mean to be just $cosx$? Do you think it is a typo?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is just the product rule. Try this:
Let $f(x) = \cos x,\quad g(x)=\frac{\mathrm d y}{\mathrm dz}.$ Then
$\frac{\mathrm d y}{\mathrm dx} = f(x)g(x)$ and so if we differentiate we get
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm d^2 y}{\mathrm dx^2} &= f'(x)g(x)+f(x)g'(x)\\
&=-\sin x\frac{\mathrm d y}{\mathrm dz} + \cos x \frac{\mathrm d }{\mathrm dx}\frac{\mathrm d y}{\mathrm dz}\\
&=-\sin x\frac{\mathrm d y}{\mathrm dz} + \cos x \frac{\mathrm d }{\mathrm dz}\frac{\mathrm d y}{\mathrm dx}\\
&=-\sin x\frac{\mathrm d y}{\mathrm dz} + \cos x \frac{\mathrm d }{\mathrm dz}\frac{\mathrm d y}{\mathrm dz}\cos x\\
&=-\sin x\frac{\mathrm d y}{\mathrm dz} + \frac{\mathrm d^2 y}{\mathrm dz^2}\cos^2 x\\
\end{align}

Comment: You're missing a negative sign, should be ${-\sin{x}}$. I tried to edit it in, but it's only 4 characters and you need at least 10 :)

Comment: Yeah. I was thinking the same. ^^

Comment: Opps, I had $-\sin x$ but must have dropped it by mistake

Comment: Thanks a lot. @DanRobertson